# Compiling PDCurses on Windows with MinGW

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I'm getting the weirdest error when I do ./configure when building nmcurses-5.9

The issue is when I try to run

```
CC="gcc -m32" LD="ld -m32" ./configure \
--prefix=/mingw \
--without-cxx-binding \
--without-ada \
--enable-warnings \
--enable-assertions \
--enable-reentrant \
--with-debug \
--with-normal \
--disable-home-terminfo \
--enable-sp-funcs \
--enable-term-driver \
--enable-interop \
--with-pthread
```

and the error I get is

```
./configure: line 21016: D:\Program: No such file or directory
```

on that line is

```
${MAKE:-make} preinstall
```

I am building this in MinGW using msys.
any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `${MAKE:-make} preinstall`, the expression `${MAKE:-make}` expands to the
value of the shell variable `MAKE`, if it is set, and otherwise to `make`.

So `MAKE` is set and expands to something probably of the form `D:\Program Files\...`,
i.e. a path with embedded spaces, which is construed as distinct tokens
`D:\Program` and `Files\...` by the shell when attempting to execute the
intended command:

```
\path\to\make preinstall
```

Instead it attempts to execute a program `D:\Program` with arguments `Files\... preinstall`
and complains that no such program exists.

With GNU `autotools` is advisable to install tools in paths that are free of
embedded spaces.